# В чём отличие тегов <s> и <strike>?

Tags: html

Оба перечёркивают текст, так в чём их различие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Тег `<s>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/s)

*Описание*

Тег `<s>` отображает текст как перечеркнутый. Этот тег аналогичен тегу `<strike>`, но в отличие от него имеет сокращенную форму записи.

Используйте `<s>` для представления вещей, которые больше не актуальны или не точны. Однако `<s>` не подходит для обозначения правок документа; для этого правильно использовать `<del>` и `<ins>`, в зависимости от обстоятельств.

Взамен тега `<s>` рекомендуется использовать стили.

*Аналог CSS*

`text-decoration`